# How to create DDL from an EDMX file at the command line?

Tags: entity-framework, edmx

How do I create a script containing the SQL DDL (to create a database) from a .EDMX file from the command line?

Answer (score 4):

We are not aware about such tool. However, you can write your own console application that will: 
1. Create an ObjectContext. 
2. Load metadata from the .edmx file. 
3. Generate DDL script using the CreateDatabaseScript() method. 
4. Save this script to file.

Comment: For me, the CreateDatabaseScript method returns an outdated DDL.